# How to add cluster marker to google maps in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to add cluster marker to google maps in angularjs.

I have already included the js file (https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/blob/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js) and the images (https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images).

However the cluster still not appears.

This is my code:

1. html:

   ```
   <section id="GoogleMaps" ng-controller="MapsController">
   <div class="container">
       <div>
           <div id="map_canvas"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </section>
   ```
2. controller:

   ```
   .controller('MapsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
        var url = 'data/LatLng.json';
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };


    $scope.initMap = function (data) {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.209500, 16.370691),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);


        data.forEach(function (item) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.LAT, item.LON),
                animation: google.maps.Animation.Bounce,
                map: map
            });

            var options = {
                imagePath: 'images/m'
            };

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker, options);

        });
    };


    $scope.loadData()
        .then($scope.initMap);

    }])
   ```
3. scripts:

   ```
   addTag('script', { src: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js' }, sync);
   addTag('script', { src: 'assets/js/markerclusterer.js' }, sync);
   ```

Any ideas how to add it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise the MarkerClusterer as following way.

```
$scope.initMap = function (data) {
 var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 7,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.209500, 16.370691),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
 var markerArray = [];


 data.forEach(function (item) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.LAT, item.LON),
         animation: google.maps.Animation.Bounce,
         map: map
     });

     markerArray.push(marker);
 });

var options = {
    imagePath: 'images/m'
};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray, options);
};
```

When you initialize it in forEach loop, it creates new object of it.